# when i have two php version in windows 7 OS, how php.exe in the cmd will find which one of php.ini

Tags: php

I have installed two PHP, one is PHP 5.2 and the other is PHP 5.4 (it's already add envionment variables).

When I run `php -v` with PHP 5.4 in the cmd, it accesses `php.ini` for PHP 5.2 version, and it triggers error for import extension. But in the `phpinfo()` it correctly find php.ini.so i use 'php -c "e:/dev/php5_4/php.ini" -v' it correctly work. But i hope when i use 'php -v' it correctly work, not '-c'. Because i will setup composer and it need specify 'php.exe' path, i hope it's PHP 5.4 path.

Why, and how can I fix this?

Comment: You can choose which ini to use in command line: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: I use 'php -c e:/dev/php5_4/php.ini'，but nothing happen.

Comment: How about `php -c "e:/dev/php5_4/php.ini" -v`?

Comment: Think you very much.it correctly find php.ini.But when i use php.exe commond i must input like this at every turn?

Comment: To guarantee expected result, you'd better do that.

Comment: I hope when i use php.exe it default access php.ini for PHP 5.4 version not PHP 5.2 version.

Comment: Update your question with your `PATH`, your PHP setup path, and what you want. Don't extend question in comment.